# Inserting data with SQLAlchemy uses column defaults when providing other values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't overwrite column defaults. I insert a row with different values for `subject` and `can_retry`. However when I inspect the table it is still `Math` and `False`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
from sqlalchemy import *

db = create_engine('sqlite:///myapp-quizzes.db')
metadata = MetaData(db)

quizzes = Table("quizzes", metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key = True),
    Column("subject", String, default = "Math"),
    Column("description", String),
    Column("answer_a", String),
    Column("answer_b", String),
    Column("answer_c", String),
    Column("answer_d", String),
    Column("can_retry", Boolean, default = False)
)
quizzes.create()

i = quizzes.insert()
i.execute({
    "subject": "Biology",
    "description": "Where is the heart?",
    "answer_a": "In the head",
    "answer_b": "In the arm",
    "answer_c": "In the gut",
    "answer_d": "Dunno",
    "can_retry": True
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The dictionaries in the list must have the exact same keys. Of course this is for multiple inserts with dictionaries.

```
quizz_list = [
  { 
     ...
     'subject': 'Math',
     'can_retry': False
  },
  {
     ...
     'subject': 'Biology',
     'can_retry': True
  }
]
```